# Adonis JS link with AWS Secrets Manager Credential

Tags: node.js, aws-secrets-manager

I want to try connecting the credential in aws secrets manager to the credential in my adonis api, is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes we can do it.

[adonisJs docs](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/file-system)

[adonis blog for aws](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/adonisjs-beginners-guide-50cc4cd5d3a8)